# Exclude file from jar using Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a built a springboot jar, and I want to exclude all logback.xml from fatjar using gradle. and I have tried in following way.

```
jar{
    exclude '/BOOT-INF/lib/**/logback.xml'
}
```

Could some one please help me how to exclude all logback.xml from dependencies using gradle.

Answer (score 4):

if you don’t care for the XML files to be copied from the `src/main/resources` to the build`/resources/main` folder (not just excluded when build`/resources/main` is copied to the War), you could use like:

```
processResources {
    exclude('manual/*.xml')
}
```

find more info [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/exclude-resource-file-from-jar-file/21215).

Comment: I need file logback.xml present in src/main/resources , I don't need logback.xml present in any of the dependencies of the jat

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where are xml files has been kept.

You can try like below and change the path accordingly.

```
sourceSets { main { resources { exclude '**/*.xml' } }  }
```

Comment: I am trying to exclude dependency resources from jar not my jar resource files

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that "excluding" things is an anti-pattern. So I'd flip your question on its head and ask "when do you need to include the files?" with the goal of including an extra folder only when it's needed (and not including the folder where it's not needed)

If the files are only needed for testing then the files should be moved to src/test/resources. If it's some other task that needs the files then I suggest you move the files to src/xxx/resources and add that folder only to the task(s) which need the files

As a convention, everything in src/main/resources goes into the jar. In my opinion this is a very sensible convention.

Comment: That's an interesting point of view. I find the need to exclude a file from a build must be a thing because the word 'exclude' exists in the language and in fact there's support for a section  called  'sourceSets' that allows for an 'exclude' option. In addition every other ide I've ever used allows for excluding files, it seems a shame that all of a sudden it's an antipattern and we shouldn't do it. Really I just want to exclude a file from a build.

Comment: Of course you can do it, and yes, gradle supports exclude. It's just better, in my opinion, to separated things into their own folders and include them only as required. Excluding specific files gets messy. It's harder for new people on your team to understand the "magic". You also have to be careful to always exclude the file(s) at all relevant steps/build tasks

Comment: Excluding is not a nice solution, but I didn't like to exclude a possible solution. You can rewrite a class with a bug inside a library that you dont have access.
I once needed that solution for a facebook sdk class.